# Crear Arbol de elementos en xml con C#

Tags: c#, xml, vscode

me gustaría crear un arbol en XML algo similar al siguiente:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ext:UBLExtensions>
   <ext:UBLExtension>
      <ext:ExtensionContent>
        ejemplo
      </ext:ExtensionContent>
   </ext:UBLExtension>
</ext:UBLExtensions>
```

Mediante la programación en C#, tengo el siguiente código:

```
public void CrearXML(string ruta)
        {
            rutaXml = ruta;
            atrDocumento = new XmlDocument();
            try
            {
                #region cabeza de pagina
                XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = atrDocumento.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
                XmlElement root = atrDocumento.DocumentElement;
                atrDocumento.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
                #endregion
                #region nodo principal                
                XmlElement ndPrincipal = atrDocumento.CreateElement("fe", "Invoice", ":");
                atrDocumento.AppendChild(ndPrincipal);
                #region atributos
                //acá no hay problemas
                #endregion
                XmlElement Elemento1 = atrDocumento.CreateElement("ext", "UBLExtension",":");
                atrDocumento.AppendChild(Elemento1); //Linea del problema
                //Primero quiero crear la primera subcapa para después hacerlo más facil el resto
                atrDocumento.Save(ruta);
                #endregion                
            }
}
```

A lo que me sale un error de ejecución en el sector referente a el `elemento1` el cual dice

> "Este documento ya tiene un nodo 'DocumentElement'."

Realmente no entiendo porque está sucediendo esto si en teoría todo debería funcionar correctamente pero no es así, ya leí algunos documentos de docs.Microsoft, leído otras lineas en StackOverflow pero hasta el momento no he encontrado una solución a este problema, estoy totalmente atento a lo que me puedan ayudar y en atender para esclarecer de ser necesario y así encontrar la solución a la situación en cuestion.
De ante mano muchas gracias.